# Installing Python modules with local Python build

Tags: python, python-module

I have python 2.7 installed locally in ~/Python2.7/ and I need the psycopg2 module. But when I try to install it with easy_install or compile it manually, I get

```
error: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/local/lib/python2.7/config/Makefile (No such file or directory)
```

I tried to change a line in ~/Python2.7/Lib/sysconfig.py from

```
return os.path.join(get_path('stdlib'), "config", "Makefile")
```

to

```
return '/home/foo/Python2.7/Makefile'
```

with no effect. What do I do to walk around this?

Comment: Try installing easy_install locally as well.

Comment: easy_install was already installed locally. Honestly, Python was not installed, only compiled, and I have only created a symlink to the binary in ~/bin/.

Comment: Does the shebang of easy_install point to your local Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the command line options: http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html#command-line-options and try fiddling around with your --install-dir .  The local install would also need to be in the PYTHONPATH environment variable.  If you are trying to install everything locally, try using pip, instead of easy_install, and setup a virtual environment (from virtualenv).

Comment: Well, the command line options are no good... install-dir is where the module, not Python, is installed. I think I'll try to persuade the admin to install python 2.7 globally, after all.

Comment: `virtualenv` is perfect for this. You build Python from source to the desired --prefix, and then you can use `virtualenv --python /path/to/your/local/python/exe ...` to create an environment in which you can install any desired package using either `easy_install` or `pip`. Without elevating privileges! Upvoting this answer since it mentions `virtualenv`.